# Изменения в списке, который является значением в словаре

Tags: python-3.x, словари

У меня словарь, где на каждый ключ есть значение, представляющее собой список из пяти целых чисел. Нужно как-то обратиться, например, ко второму числу из этого списка, чтобы можно было прибавить к нему другое число. Можно ли это как-то сделать?  Помогите, пожалуйста :_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала вам необходимо вбрать значение из словаря по ключу, затем выбрать значение из списка указав его индекс и далее работать с ним:

```
value_list = my_dict['key1']
second_number = value_list[1]
```

Либо вы можете сразу присвоить значение элементу списка из словаря:

```
my_dict['key1'][1] = my_dict['key1'][1] + 10
```